# WebPack: Include Non-Bundle Files In Watch-List to Trigger Rebuild

Tags: configuration, include, bundle, webpack-dev-server, watch

## WebPack: Include Non-Bundle Files In Watch-List to Trigger Rebuild

That is, point to files (somewhere) that are *not* to be included in any final bundles, but *do* trigger a rebuild of the aforementioned bundles.

### Sidenote:

I have already:

- Googled around using a few search terms
- Looked at Webpack's `watchOptions` -- even tried `include` & `included` for `"./path/to/target/file.json"` & `/\.\/path\/to\/target\/file\.json/` (just for kicks)
- Skimmed through Webpack Plugins for anything with "Watch", "Trigger" & "Change"

No luck :(

#### Here is [generally] what I am looking for:

~/webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: modules,  // <-- COMES FROM `./app.json`
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.[hash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    },
    ...
    watchOptions: {
        include: './app.json',  // <-- NOT INCLUDED IN BUNDLE (contains `modules` at key `entry`)
    },
};
```

~/app.json

```
{
    "environments": {
        "production": {             THESE NEED TO BE WATCHED!!!
            ...                                 |
        },                                      |
        "development": {                        |
            ...                                 |
        }                                       |
    },                                          |
    "modules": {                                V
        "x.component": [ "./src/.../x.component.ts", "./src/.../x.component.scss" ],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

#### OR

```
webpack-dev-server --watch ./app.json
```

### Question

How can I watch non-bundle files and trigger a rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could make good use of [webpack-watch-files-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-watch-files-plugin). It watches for changes of arbitrary folders.